# Deleting part after specific character and that character

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to delete data in cell after specific character including that character.

For example if I have in one cell `379_795;0` I want to have it without `;0` and only `379_795`. What function should I use it?

I tried googling but I can not find anything that would help me. There should be already defined function. I do not think I should write it in VBA.

Comment: `Split(cellValue, ";")(0)`

Comment: You can simply use a build-in function called text-to-columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a simple formula:

```
=LEFT(A:A,FIND(";",A:A)-1)
```

This uses `FIND` to find the position of the semicolon `;` and then `LEFT` to return only the left part of the text until the position of the semicolon. We need the `-1` to remove the semicolon aswell.

The result will be:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Cut off everything after the semicolon (including the semicolon).</sup>*

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. But this does not work for me. I just copied your formula and I get that window There is a problem with this formula. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Alena The reason is that you probably don't use an us-english Excel (which this formula is intended to be used with). Which language version of Excel are you using? Try to replace the comma in the formula with a semicolon: `=LEFT(A:A;FIND(";";A:A)-1)`. Or use the [Excel Translator](https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/) to translate the (us-english) formula into your county version.

Comment: You were right. I always have to change languages because of work and sometimes I forgot to change the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just try (assuming you have your string in `A1` cell):

```
=MID(A1;1;FIND(";";A1;1)-1)
```